# Storing Raphael objects inside another object for later manipulation

Tags: javascript, raphael

Soo... pretty much a noob, have pity on me for any obvious mistakes.

I'm trying to use Raphaël to create some clickable (or not) shapes.

However, since I want to be flexible in how the actual rendering I wan't it to be objects containing raphael shapes, not just an array of raphael shapes.

Basically trying to separate the drawing from the object properties.

My non-working attempt below:

```
var Box = function (where, type, id) {
    // This is the object containing rendering info

    this.id = id

    this.posx = coords.topLeft.x;
    this.posy = coords.topLeft.y;

    this.width = type.w; // length 
    this.height = type.h; // height 

    this.color = baseColors.black;
    this.line = baseColors.white;

    this.paper = where;

    this.raphShp = this.drawMe()
    this.clickMe()  
}

Box.prototype.drawMe = function () {
    // Function to be called for drawing the shape 
    var box = this.paper.rect(this.posx, this.posy, this.width, this.height);
    box.attr({fill: this.color,stroke: this.line,'stroke-width': '1','stroke-opacity': '1'}).data('name', 'box' + this.id);

    // trying to pass the raphael shape back to the object
    return this.paper.getById(box.id)
}

Box.prototype.clickMe = function () {
    // trying to add clickable property to the shape
        this.raphShp.click(function(evt) {
            this.rotate(45);
            console.log('rotate')
        }); 
}
```

Adding the clickable property in the drawMe works of course. But I want to be able to do it separately.

What painfully obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what exactly not working here?

Comment: Apparently, my problem had nothing to do with this code, see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/89dL5/2/

Don't forget to instantiate your object:

```
var b = new Box(Raphael(100, 100, 500, 500), [etc], [etc]);
```

You're probably doing something wrong elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, it seems I'm doing something wrong with trying to get objects clickable when they aren't in the top div.